# HAProxy: ACL to forward to different webservers based on directory

Tags: apache-2.2, haproxy, lighttpd

basically I have a raspberry pi with multiple webserver daemons on different ports, to be specific lighttpd, apache, and the ADAFruit WebIDE. Basically here are the ways i need it to work[how would you best write the config file?]:

```
http://RasberryPi:80/ > http://localhost:8080/
https://RasberryPi:443/ > http://localhost:8080/
(or if it cant be done as root folder to be /apache)

http://RaspberryPi:80/WebIDE > http://localhost:8081/
https://RasberryPi:443/WebIDE > http://localhost:8081/

http://RasberryPi:80/lighttp > http://localhost:8082/
https://RasberryPi:443/lighttp > http://localhost:8082/
```

i know it should be something like what follows, but what if i dont want load balancing? and i do want https even if the destination server doesnt support it?:

```
frontend http-in
    bind 10.254.23.225:80
    acl has_special_uri path_beg /special
    use_backend special_server if has_special_uri
    default_backend webfarm

backend webfarm
    balance roundrobin
    cookie SERVERID insert
    option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server webA 10.254.23.4:80 cookie webA check
    server webB 10.248.23.128:80 cookie webB check

backend special_server
    balance roundrobin
    cookie SERVERID insert
    option httpchk HEAD /check.txt HTTP/1.0
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
    server webC 10.0.0.1:80 cookie webC check
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically almost there. Configure three backends:

1. `apache`, with only the server `localhost:8080`
2. `lighttpd`, with server `localhost:8082`
3. `webide`, with server `localhost:8081`

Make `apache` your default backend. Add `acl`s to use the other backends if the URI starts with the appropriate path.